# Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" added automatically to aspx page after updating from Visual Studio 2013 to 2019

Tags: c#, html, tags

I have recently updated from VS2013 to 2019. I also updated Dev Express controls from version 15.2 to 21.1.

After that this markup was added twice automatically to the aspx pages, once before the `<html>` tag and once after:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

In the same pages the following code was added before the `</head>` tag:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef"> 
<xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_Editor 
msdt:dt="string">*********</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft- 
com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_Editor>
<mso:Order msdt:dt="string">****************</mso:Order>
<mso:ComplianceAssetId msdt:dt="string"></mso:ComplianceAssetId>
<mso:_ExtendedDescription msdt:dt="string"></mso:_ExtendedDescription>
<mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_Author 
msdt:dt="string">**********</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft- 
com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_Author>
<mso:ContentTypeId 
msdt:dt="string">0x***************************</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:_SourceUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:_SourceUrl>
<mso:_SharedFileIndex msdt:dt="string"></mso:_SharedFileIndex>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->
```

This is being added only to aspx pages and only those that are not connected to Master pages.

When running the program I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I delete the Sharepoint tag I get the following error:

> Unknown server tag 'SharePoint:CTFieldRefs'.

If delete all these additions the program seems to work fine.

What does all of this mean? Why are these added?

Is there any need for this? Can deleting this cause any problems?

Comment: I noticed this as well, and it breaks the funcion of my ASPX pages, see here: 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306110/i-got-custom-scripts-enabled-but-my-static-aspx-web-page-doesnt-work-in-all